# How to set document.cookie from one frame and get it in another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I have `javascript` code which sets `document.cookie` from the frame, then I got it in the second frame. I have recently noticed that started from February `document.cookie` is an empty string. I tried with the new params, but couldn't set cookies. Which is the best workaround to do this?

Comment: We'll need some more details. Is the document for both of these frames on the same origin?

Comment: My general page is `aaa.com` and frames are on the same domain but different from the parent. the first's URL is  `bbb.com/frame1` and the second's is `bbb.com/frame2`. I need to set cookies from `frame1` and get in `frame2`